# Ruby On Rails custom ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to have custom ids for a table and not use the default auto_increment. Is that possible? I have turned :id => false and later on I create a t.column :id, :bigint
But when I create a new record the id is set to NULL

Is there anyway to bypass this behaviour.
I could set my primary key to a field uid (it is actually facebook id) but usually it breaks for me as relations usually look for the id field

Comment: sorry what?  You turn off the thing that fills in the value, and then want to bypass that it's not filling in the number?  Please expand your question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly going to be easier to use Rails' surrogate autoincrement ID as your primary ID.

There's no problem having a second unique column facebook_id and performing all your searches based on that field, but for the compatability reasons you mention (i.e. plugin authors making assumptions they shouldn't) I'd stick with Rails defaults as much as sensible. The performance issues relating to primary keys vs unique keys are minimal

Comment: @baash05 agreed, try and submit real answers not critique, there are certain cases in which making a custom id is useful for those looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402189/specify-custom-primary-key-in-migration

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the problem is. Of course id is NULL when you disable auto_increment for the id column and don't insert an id value by hand.

Btw: You can define the foreign and primary keys for relations. It is no problem to use facebook_id as primary key.

Comment: I insert by hand User.create(:id=>9459405) but it doesn t matter i ll stic to Rails autoincrement defaults as i had some problems in the past