# Specify custom primary key in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a data structure:

```
  t.integer :userID
  t.string :apikey
  t.integer :characterID
```

The userID should be the primary key (name is not important, it can default to `:id`). However, I don't want it to be auto incrementing or anything else, just take the value provided and write it into the database.

How do I have to adjust the migration and the model to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
 create_table(:my_table, :primary_key => 'userID') do |t|
   # Primary key column will be created automatically
   # Do not create here
   # t.column :userID, :integer, :null => false
   ...
 end
```

Or

```
create_table :my_table, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.integer :userID
  t.string :apikey
  t.integer :characterID
  t.timestamps
 end
 execute "ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (userID);"
```

And don't forget to put this line somewhere in  model:

```
 set_primary_key :userID
```

Comment: In your first example, shouldn't it be `:integer`? `userID` still is an `integer`, not varchar.

Comment: @MohitJain: is it necessary to put the "set_primary_key" using both methods you suggested, or the "set_primary_key" is meant to be used on the second method only?

Comment: @Eduardo In both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of circumventing the ActiveRecord model, I made `userID` a normal column and used

```
validates_uniqueness_of :userID, :message => "userID needs to be unique"
```

on the model to validate it.

Comment: Did you add an index? If you are going to search using the `userId` that is essential.