# Rails Migrations and non-standard data types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

#### Initial problem

In my Rails application I need to work with data from a legacy database, with large numbers as primary keys. Numbers that exceed the limits of both [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)'s and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-numeric.html)'s 4-byte INT or INTEGER data type. But that's exactly the data type that Rails' adapters translate "`integer`" into.

#### My workaround

That was not an issue in development, since SQLite has only one integer type accepting large numbers. But for staging/production (i.e. for use with anything *but* SQLite), I had to manually edit the `schema.rb` file to replace `t.integer "id"` with `t.column "id", 'BIGINT'`.  Then load the schema, import the data, and it works.

#### The problem with the workaround

Now, everytime I run a Rails migration to make a minor change to the database schema, the entire `schema.rb` file is automatically re-generated, and all my `id` columns are just `t.integer` again. As before, this isn't a problem in development (SQLite), but it probably will be in production, won't it? I'd hate to have to drop the database, load the schema and reimport all data every time I need to add or rename a column – I'd much rather use migrations for this.

The workaround for me thus far has been to make a backup copy of `schema.rb` before migrating, and then to merge the additions made by the migration with my own ones. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: I *know* I'm not supposed to edit `schema.rb`, but I couldn't find a good alternative, that's one of the reasons I'm asking the question.

Comment: Similar: [Specify custom primary key in migration][1].

Do you can use TEXT instead BIGINT?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402189/specify-custom-primary-key-in-migration

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/1095974) a solution to hack in bigint primary keys in mysql2 and postgresql:

In environment.rb:

```
    # Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:big_primary_key] = "BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY".freeze
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:big_primary_key] = "bigserial primary key".freeze

# Initialize the rails application
YourAppName::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, will definitely try this out!