# Adding a reference to a non-integer column in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have studied several questions on this topic today. I know that, I can use `t.references` in migration to add a reference. But, If a table has non-integer primary key, how do I add reference to that column?

I have a table with this definition

```
    create_table :sessions, id: false do |t|
      t.string  :session, primary_key: true, limit: 10  

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

How do I add a reference to the `session` column (the name doesn't matter here), which is a string from another table migration. I tested with `t.references` but that just add an integer column. I know that I can use `add column`. But how to do that without from `create_table` method directly?

**Clarification for duplicate flag**
This question is flagged as duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846090), but it is actually not. Because I am not asking about setting up table with non-default non-integer primary key, because I already set up that table. I am asking about referencing this type of table from another table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails non-integer primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846090/rails-non-integer-primary-key)

Comment: @ABMagil I don't think its a duplicate since Anwar asks about *references* to non-integer primary keys – not the primary keys themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the references helper, you would need to use the string type, and add an index for faster lookups. If your other model is "Record":

```
rails generate migration AddSessionIdToRecords session:string:index
```

Which should generate a migration like so:

```
def change
  add_column :records, :session_id, :string
  add_index :records, :session_id
end
```

Since you're using unconventional naming, you'd need to specify the primary key in the model and the relation definition:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "session"

  has_many :records, primary_key: "session"
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :session, primary_key: "session"
end
```

Comment: I have setup almost like this, but i think, it is `foreign_key: "session"` instead of `primary_key: "session"`. You should check

Comment: What did you name the column on your other table ("`records`")? That's the foreign_key, so if you named it `session`, the foreign_key would be `"session"`

Comment: The point is I have to use foreign_key option, not primary_key option

Answer (score 4):

Since rails version `4.2.7` You can specify `type` into the `add_reference` helper.
Suppose you have table `records` and you want to have reference of `sessions` inside `records`. Then you can do the following :

```
add_reference :records, :sessions, type: :string, foreign_key: {to_table: :sessions, primary_key: :session}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have to add primary_key in class Session & Record

```
def change
  add_column :records, :session_id, :string
  add_index :records, :session_id
  add_foreign_key :records, :sessions, column: :session_id, primary_key: "your_primary_key_name_in_sessions_table"
end
```

and that will be all.

Comment: Why should I use `:session_id` as `string`?

Answer (score 1):

I've arrived at the conclusion that, without using `foreign_key` which is introduced in rails 4.2, I can't truly reference another column, only creating index as suggested by [this answer from eirikir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32168935/1039893).

From rails 4.2, I can use foreign key like this

In session Table migration

```
create table :sessions, id: false do |t|
  t.string "session", primary_key: true
  t.timestamp null: false
end
```

For a record table to reference the `session` primary key

```
create table :records do |t|
  t.string "session", null: false
  ..
  .. # other attributes
end

add_index :records, :session
add_foreign_key :records, :sessions, column: :session, primary_key: :session
```

Here, the `column:` option fixes, on which column i want to create the foreign key and the `primary_key:` option fixes, the primary key of the referenced table, which is here `session`.