# Creating custom primary keys in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle11g, primary-key

In my Rails application which works with Oracle database (version 11g) I need primary keys to be `String`s, not `Integer`s. For example, in my `Product` model I need primary keys like `"p001"`, `"p002"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
class AddProductWithDifferentPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord:Migration
  def change
    create_table :table, id: false do |t|
      t.string :id, null: false
      # other columns
      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```

Don't forget to also add this line to your table model so rails knows how to find your new primary key!

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id

  # rest of code
end
```

Hope this helps.  And credit should go to 
  [A K H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623261/a-h-k)

For more information you can check out his as well as other answers. [primary key info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846090/rails-non-integer-primary-key)

Comment: Thanks,  But how do I add the string sequence to primary key in the rails application itself, or should I create a PLSQL sequence for it.