# How to set custom table associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my DB Schema. **NOTE the 'studentid' and 'student_studentid'**

```
  create_table "students", force: true do |t|
   t.string  "fname",      limit: 45
   t.string  "lname",      limit: 45
   t.string  "guardian",   limit: 45
   t.string  "phone",      limit: 45
   t.string  "email",      limit: 45
   t.integer "user_id"
   t.date    "createdate"
   t.string  "studentid",  limit: 45
  end

  create_table "term_reports", force: true do |t|
   t.string  "student_studentid", limit: 10
   t.integer "subject_id"
   t.integer "score"
   t.integer "position"
   t.integer "term"
   t.integer "year"
   t.integer "user_id"
   t.date    "ceatedate"
  end
```

I am assigning custom id's to the students. How can I use these columns for table associations? I want to be able to say **TermReport.find('my-id-10').student**.

Here is what I have tried but wont work.

```
class TermReport < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :student, :primary_key => :studentid
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :term_reports, primary_key: :stuent_studentid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using the incorrect attribute for the association. You can look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more references

```
TermReport
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: studentid

Student
  has_many :term_reports, foreign_key: :stuent_studentid
```

Comment: TermReport.find('jm-90').student still doesn't work See the output in my answer.

Comment: you can refer to this on how to set custom primary keys for student https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579245/creating-custom-primary-keys-in-rails-application

Answer (score 0):

TermReport is still using id as its primary key. See the output below.

```
TermReport.find('jm-90').student

 TermReport Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `term_reports`.* FROM `term_reports`  WHERE  `term_reports`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find TermReport with 'id'=jm-90
```