# Change Primary Key Issue Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, key

I followed this guide on how to change the Primary Key:

http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/09/30/changing-the-primary-key-type-in-ruby-on-rails-models/comment-page-1

Here is my code:

```
class Pk2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :contracts, :id # remove existing primary key
    rename_column :contracts, :contractId, :id # rename existing UDID column
    execute "ALTER TABLE contracts ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end

  def down
    # Remove the UDID primary key. Note this would differ based on your database
    execute "ALTER TABLE contracts DROP CONSTRAINT table_pkey;"
    rename_column :contracts, :id, :contractId
    add_column :contracts, :id, :primary_key
  end
end
```

The error I keep getting is "Syntax around ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY"

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Post the `full error stack`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050978/problems-setting-a-custom-primary-key-in-a-rails-4-migration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column

Comment: Does the migration successfully `rename` the `:contractId` column to `:id`?

Comment: No, it's still contractId @RichPeck

Comment: Why don't you try running the migration successfully, then creating a new migration with the `execute` command?

Comment: that worked...thanks a lot @RichPeck! I broke the code into 3 separate migrations... I do wonder why it didn't work when I ran the whole migration together though.

Comment: I don't know! It was just a hunch -- I'll write an answer to clarify the solution for posterity

Comment: @RichPeck when I click "Show" I get this error

No route matches {:id=>#<Contract name: "third contract", awardDate: "2014-05-23", expirationDate: "2014-05-23", awardAmount: nil, obligatedAmount: nil, invoicedAmount: nil, created_at: "2014-05-23 21:25:50", updated_at: "2014-05-24 14:28:32", id: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]

NOTICE it says missing required keys: [:id] - could this have something to do with changing the PK??

Comment: It says ` id: nil` - basically means that attribute is not present in your db. Have you checked if the `id` (the value) exsists in the db? If so, it could be a PK issue; else it will likely be that you've not populated the `id` column for that record

Comment: @RichPeck I checked my db schema and there is an :id field. Correction - I'm not getting this error when I click on the "show" page. I am getting this error when I am on the index page... Please help lol

Comment: Hmmmmm - are you sure you've got a value in the column?

Comment: Yes @RichPeck:

  create_table "contracts", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "awardDate"
    t.date     "expirationDate"
    t.decimal  "awardAmount",     precision: 10, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "obligatedAmount", precision: 10, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "invoicedAmount",  precision: 10, scale: 3
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "id"
  end

Comment: Nooo I meant have you have actually got a "value" in the `id` column? Like do you have some data available?

Comment: @RichPeck The Contracts that I made before I changed the primary key do not have an :id value. However, Contracts that I made after changing the primary key do have a :id field. I just went into my console and gave an :id value to the earlier ones and I can load the index page now. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!

Comment: :) no problem! Keep the questions coming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seemed to be that the OP separated the migration into 3 files:

```
1. Remove `:id` column
2. Rename `:contractId` column to `:id`
3. run `execute "ALTER TABLE contracts ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"`
```

This allowed the OP to successfully run the migration

Some other resources:

> - [Using Rails, how can I set my primary key to not be an integer-typed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column)
> - [Problems setting a custom primary key in a Rails 4 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050978/problems-setting-a-custom-primary-key-in-a-rails-4-migration)

Comment: Thanks Pavan - hope things are progressing for you? Where are you based btw?

Comment: I stay in Banglore,India :)