# Update old record instead of creating a new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following table:

```
event_id  value   created_at        updated_at
1         15.2    2014/01/01 00:00  2014/01/01 00:00
2         15.5    2014/01/01 00:10  2014/01/01 00:10
3         15.9    2014/01/01 00:20  2014/01/01 00:20
```

However, if a new Event has same value as the previous (as in newest in time) Event, then the previous Event should have "updated_at" set to current time and no new Event should be created.

In the example above, if I do Event.new(:value => 15.9), then Event with id 3 should have its updated_at set to current time - and that should be the only change.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I have tried fiddling with Active Record callbacks, but fail when aborting creation (using rollback). It is of course possible to solve using a special "constructor" method, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Google for `find_or_create_by`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Event.where(value: params[:value]).first_or_create.touch
```

or in event.rb

```
before_save :update_if_existing

private 
def update_if_existing
  if event = Event.find_by(value: value)
    event.touch # updates the updated_at timestamp if the existing event
    false       # prevents the current event from being inserted into the db
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer since it puts logic in the model object rather than the controller.

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind that it still returns the new unsaved `Event` and not the `Event` that already exists. You may need to handle that in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way, let's say `@event` is the object and before saving you want to check the value

```
unless @event.value == Event.last.value     
  @event.save
else
  Event.last.update_attributes(:updated_at => DateTime.now)
end
```

or you can do this in a single line using ternary operator

```
(@event.value == Event.last.value) ? (Event.last.update_attributes(:updated_at => DateTime.now)) : (@event.save)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Event.find_or_create_by_value(params[:value]).touch
```

This method will find event by value or create one if event with this value doesn't exist. Touch method will update `updated_at` timestamp for this record.

Answer (score 0):

Since your definition of Event is that no two events should have the same `value` - you should add a unique index on that field, which will also make any such operations much quicker.

Actually, since your event is not defined by its `id` but by its `value`, consider changing its [primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402189/specify-custom-primary-key-in-migration/6402240#6402240) to `value`:

```
create_table(:event, :primary_key => 'value') do |t|
  t.column :userID, :decimal, :null => false
  ...
end

class Event
  set_primary_key :value
  ...
end
```

Now you can simply do:

```
Event.find_or_create_by_value(params[:value]).touch
```

Comment: Two events in the table can have the same value, but not in sequence. I.e. 15.2, 15.5, 15.2 is ok. But not 15.2, 15.2.

Comment: @Ciryon - it was not apparent from your question, sorry. In that case,  I think only RSB got it right... the rest of the answers look for it globally.