# Rails Active Record table id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails handle table id's automatically, in an incremental way. What if I want to stop this incremental behavior? I am actually building a website that uses the FB API and I d like to set the user id to be the facebook id. I am new to rails, so is that possible?

Comment: [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969427/ruby-on-rails-custom-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its possible, but i would just add another column into your table (in the migration file) with the facebook id.

Answer (score 0):

In your migrations file, have something like this:

```
create_table :users, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.integer :facebook_id
end
```

and in your model class

**Rails 3**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :facebook_id
end
```

**Rails 4**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :facebook_id
end
```